# My car jerks when I put it in drive

Tags: suzuki

I was driving and everything was perfectly fine and I stopped at a stop sign and my car started jerking. When I popped the hood to look at it, the car was put into drive the whole engine started bouncing up and down

Comment: What's the model, year, mileage?

Answer (score 1):

I assume there's a question somewhere in your original post?

Check the engine/transmission mounts. Depending on the make/model, mileage, as well as use-and-abuse, those need to be replaced occasionally and they will cause the symptoms you are describing.

You should be okay to drive home or a service station, especially if you take it easy during acceleration and braking.